# Testing for a timer to run out in Cucumber and Capybara

Tags: rspec, sinatra, cucumber

So I have a Sinatra app and I am trying to test in Cucumber an event that will happen when the timer runs out (I use FlipClock.js for this).

It works fine manually but how or what is the approach in letting the timer run out and seeing if the page was redirected?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out.

But this will be dependent if you set up the way FlipClock.js get's it's timer variable.

For me, it was being stored in a mode, so what I did was I simply changed the value of that in the model BEFORE I accessed the page that has the timer so that I could set it to 2 seconds and only have to wait 2 seconds instead of my timer's default value of 30 seconds.